# How do you get the winning kill cam in Modern Warfare 2?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2

Does the player of the kill cam get set randomly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The game winning killcam is the video of the kill that caused the game to end. (The last kill of the game.)

Comment: Though of course most playlists don't have game-winning killcams at all because their outcome isn't based on the highest number of kills.

Comment: No game is based on highest number of kills. The points are used for ranking in a game.

Comment: @PoweRoy I think you are mistaken. The only way to earn those points is to kill the opposition. XP awarded for calling in and destroying killstreak rewards and for assists doesn't affect the team's score in Team Deathmatch or an individual's scoreboard position in Free-for-All. Free-for-All requires 25 kills; Team Deathmatch, 75 and Ground War, 100.

Comment: Learned something new, thought it was just point based (+ when killing, - on suicide, + on using killstreak rewards)

Comment: I thought it was the most efficient or the most "beautiful" or whatever. I understand now why in free-for-all the kill cam is not always shown. We don't have a kill cam when the time limit is reached.

Comment: @Luc you only get a kill-cam if the game is a `kill all enemies` type game (FFA, HC-TDM, or TDM) and the score limit is reached before the time limit.